# Where statement with multiple 'Not Like'

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write the following statement:

```
WHERE field LIKE 'Pandora' AND field Not Like 'radio', 'digital', 'internet';
```

Translation: Select where field is like Pandora and not like radio, digital, or internet.

Is there a way to write this statement without writing Not Like 3 times with ANDs in between?

Thank you

Answer (score 14):

If "field" is not just single words, you would need to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE '%Pandora%' AND field NOT LIKE '%radio%' AND field NOT LIKE '%internet%' and field NOT LIKE '%digital%';
```

Answer (score 8):

First of all, your query is redundant, in that if `field` is [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) `'pandora'`, then the other conditions will by default return false.

There is no possible way that `field` can be equal to `'Pandora'`, `'radio'`, `'digital'`, and `'internet'`.

As a result, you can simplify your query using the following example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM example
 WHERE field = 'Pandora';
```

If the two conditions represent two separate fields, then you can use the [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) operator to enforce the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) while still allowing for further [pattern matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/pattern-matching.html):

```
SELECT *
  FROM example
 WHERE field_1 = 'Pandora'
   AND field_2 NOT REGEXP '^(radio|digital|internet)$';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're searching for specific words, you can use `NOT IN()`

```
WHERE field LIKE 'Pandora' AND field NOT IN('radio', 'digital', 'internet');
```

If you need the wildcard `%` in your search you'll need to use multiple `LIKE`s.

Comment: How to make `like`? ex.: **link not in** ?